# Java Large database inserts

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a database in which I need to insert batches of data (around 500k records at a time). I was testing with derby and was seeing insert times of about 10-15minutes for this many records (I was doing a batch insert in Java).

Does this time seem slow (working on your average laptop)? And are there approaches to speeding it up?

thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This time seems perfectly reasonable, and is in agreement with times I have observed.  If you want it to go faster, you need use bulk insert options and disable safety features:

- Use PreparedStatements and batches of 5,000 to 10,000 records unless it MUST be one transaction
- Use bulk loading options in the DBMS
- Disable integrity checks temporarily for insert
- Disable indexes temporarily or delete indexes and re-create them post-insert
- Disable transaction logging and re-enable afterward.

**EDIT: Database transactions are limited by disk I/O, and on laptops and most hard drives, the important number is seek time for the disk.**

Laptops tend to have rather slow disks, at 5400 rpm.  At this speed, seek time is about 5 ms. If we assume one seek per record (an over-estimate in most cases), it would take 40 minutes (500000 * 5 ms) to insert all rows.  Now, the use of caching mechanisms and sequencing mechanisms reduces this somewhat, but you can see where the problem comes from.

I am (of course) vastly oversimplifying the problem, but you can see where I'm going with this; it's unreasonable to expect databases to perform at the same speed as sequential bulk I/O.  You've got to apply some sort of indexing to your record, and that takes time.